# Explicit call vuex actions in the `.vue` component detach/ready function

Tags: mvvm, ecmascript-6, vuex, vue.js

I'm trying on vue-js and vuex on my project.

I've defined a `store.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
    user: {}
};

const mutations = {
    SET_CURRENT_USER (state, data) {
        state.user = data;
    }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    mutations
});
```

And my `actions.js`:

```
export const readCurrentUser = function({dispatch, state}) {
    let api = require('../api/resources');
    api.User.get({
        action: 'current'
    }).then(function(response) {
        dispatch('SET_CURRENT_USER', response.data);
    });
};
```

And then, so in my `App.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <a @click="readCurrentUser">read current user</a>
</template>

<script>
    import store from '../vuex/store'
    import { readCurrentUser } from '../vuex/actions'

    export default {
        replace: false,
        store: store,
        data: function () {
            return {
            };
        },
        vuex: {
            actions: {
                readCurrentUser: readCurrentUser
            }
        },
        attached: function() {
            // !!!!  HERE IS THE POINT !!!!
            // How can I trigger `readCurrentUser` action here?
        }
    }
</script>
```

I the above case, when I click on the `<a @click="readCurrentUser">` the action was fired as expected.

But I want the action trigger on every time the app attached, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution is so simple.

As the `vuex.actions` method would be registered on the current vm object.

So, calling:

```
attached: function() {
    this.readCurrentUser();
}
```

Just works!